# MSTest Login to web app and assert web app is loaded before beginning tests

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I am currently using MSTest in visual studio 2019 and am having an issue with selenium finding an element on the dashboard after login. After some debugging I found that the login method that I have set in my OneTimeSetUp method isn't fully finishing, before the other tests in the test class run., isn't this weird behavior? I would expect for my login method with an assert that the page is loaded to finish before moving to the other tests being that it is in the OneTimeSetUp method. Am I doing something wrong? Is there something that anyone would recommend? Again, I am trying to login and validate that the dashboard is loaded before running the test methods in the test class. Thank you!

Here is my login method:

```
  public void Login()
    {
        var _driver = DriverHelper.Driver;

        //Creates a login page object
        var loginPage = new HomeBankingLoginPage();
        
        //Enters login credentials
        loginPage.UserName.SendKeys(getElementsXML("userName"));
        loginPage.Password.SendKeys(getElementsXML("password"));
        loginPage.Submit.Click();

        WebDriverWait implicitlyWait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        IWebElement firstResult = implicitlyWait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.LinkText("Transfer")));
        
    }
```

Here is my oneTimeSetUp method:

```
 //Executes before tests start
    //Opens Homebanking URL and Login
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        Login();
    }
```

Comment: Again, I am trying to login and validate that the dashboard is loaded  - Can we have a sample code, how did you do this ?  We can suggest if something is missing

Comment: @cruisepandey Is that More of what you are looking for?

Comment: @Kode : I believe that should be sufficient. Please see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

See this line,

```
WebDriverWait implicitlyWait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```

I know that `implicitlyWait` is just a reference. But `new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));` this is Explicit waits. [See here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/)

as well as I do not see assertion. What I would suggest is :-

1. Use `Explicit wait` to login into the application.
2. Assert the `dashboard page` (either `title`, or `webpage heading or Profile pic`, just make sure whatever you are **asserting should be one of the last loaded element in UI after login**)
3. Your next test method after login should be invoked.

I will be using `[TestInitialize]` -

> Marks a method that should be called before each test method. One such
> method should be present per test class.

**Sample code :-**

```
 [TestClass]
    public class TestClass
    {
        
        public void Login()
        {
           var _driver = DriverHelper.Driver;
           _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // This is implicit wait
           //Creates a login page object
           var loginPage = new HomeBankingLoginPage();
        
           //Enters login credentials
           loginPage.UserName.SendKeys(getElementsXML("userName"));
           loginPage.Password.SendKeys(getElementsXML("password"));
           loginPage.Submit.Click();
           
           //If you have NuGet, search for DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers, and import that namespace into your class.
           var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
           var element = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.LinkText("Transfer")));
           string dashBoardText = element.Text;
           string expectedText = "you should write expected text from transfer from Dashboard here"
           Assert.IsTrue(expectedText.Contains(dashBoardText));
           
           // if the above does not work, you can still try with lamba expression :- 

           WebDriverWait explicitWait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
           IWebElement firstResult = explicitWait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.LinkText("Transfer")));
           string dashBoardText = firstResult.Text;
           string expectedText = "you should write expected text from transfer from Dashboard here"
           Assert.IsTrue(expectedText.Contains(dashBoardText));
        }
    
        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInitialize()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside TestInitialize");
            Login();
        }
 
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside TestMethod");
        }
 
        [TestCleanup]
        public void TestCleanup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside TestCleanup");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the implicit wait, then just try and locate an element you know should be visible when the page is ready. The driver will then wait for the implicit wait time before throwing an exception.

```
    public void Login()
    {
        var _driver = DriverHelper.Driver;
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

        // Let set the page timeout too, just to be safe.
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

        //Creates a login page object
        var loginPage = new HomeBankingLoginPage();
        
        //Enters login credentials
        loginPage.UserName.SendKeys(getElementsXML("userName"));
        loginPage.Password.SendKeys(getElementsXML("password"));
        loginPage.Submit.Click();

        // Locate the element you know should be there, it will time out after the implicitWait.
        var transferElement = _driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Transfer"));        
    }
```